# De/Serialize C# data object with nested derived objects to/from JSON

Tags: c#, json

Is there C# library that can serialize tree-like structure of .NET/C# strongly typed objects in a single call?

EDIT: I want to be able to deserialize JSON into variable of type object (or some other root class, but object would be preferable) and then find out what I just deserialized by calling GetType() on this variable. So type of each instance of each class (except bool/int/float/string) and each List<> should be stored as part of serialized JSON and retrieved automatically.

For example if I have these C# classes:

```
public class House
{
    public int Number;
    public List<Room> Rooms;
}

public class Room
{
    public string Name;
    public int Floor;
}

public class Bathroom : Room
{
    public bool IsWet;
}
```

And initialize my in-memory data structure like this (note that I use generic List class, not C# array):

```
House myHouse = new House();
myHouse.Number = 13;
myHouse.Rooms = new List<Room>();
myHouse.Rooms.Add(new Room());
myHouse.Rooms[0].Name = "some room";
myHouse.Rooms[0].Floor = 0;
myHouse.Rooms.Add(new Bathroom());
myHouse.Rooms[0].Name = "other room";
myHouse.Rooms[0].Floor = 3;
myHouse.Rooms[0].IsWet = true;
```

After that I want to be able to call something like this:

```
string jsonHouse = JSON.Serialize(myHouse);
```

To get (for example) this in my jsonHouse variable *(EDIT: note that it stores type of each class as part of JSON. Also note the instance of derived class BathRoom stored in List)*:

```
{
  "class": "House",
  "Number": "13",
  "Rooms": [
    {
      "class": "Room",
      "Name": "some room"
      "Floor": "0",
    },
    {
      "class": "Bathroom",
      "Name": "other room"
      "Floor": "0",
      "IsWet": "true",
    },
  ],
}
```

and finally call something like this:

```
House copyOfMyHouse = JSON.Deserialize(jsonHouse);
```

EDIT: this (right above) call seems to be misleading. instead of above call I should expect deserialization to be like this:

```
object copyOfMyHouse = JSON.Desrialize(jsonHouse);
```

To get instance of class House in my copyOfMyHouse variable (of type object) without specifying to JSON.Deserialize what type do I expect from it - I may not know it in advance.

to get exact copy of what I had in myHouse variable, with an instance of List generic class containing references to exact copies of two instances of Room class.

*Is there any JSON serializer written in C# that can do this?*

Preferably FOSS/FLOSS one that can be (legally) used in commercial projects.

Format of JSON string may be different from what I used above as example (e.g. your proposed solution may store List as JSON objects instead of arrays, other text formats like BSON or XML are acceptable)
Single-call use for any number of nesting levels is mandatory - otherwise any JSON serializer would fit.
Also ability to serialize Dictionary to JSON object is desirable.

Please ask clarifying questions if my description of what I look for is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to serialize/deserialize an object containing derived types. The solution is using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). It's very simple and easy to use. Here is an example with your data:

```
House myHouse = new House();
myHouse.Number = 13;

myHouse.Rooms = new List<Room>();

Room room1 = new Room();
room1.Name = "some room";
room1.Floor = 0;
myHouse.Rooms.Add(room1);

Room room2 = new Room();
room2.Name = "other room";
room2.Floor = 3;
myHouse.Rooms.Add(room2);

Bathroom bathroom = new Bathroom();
bathroom.Name = "Bathroom";
bathroom.Floor = 2;
bathroom.IsWet = true;
myHouse.Rooms.Add(bathroom);

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myHouse, settings);
Console.WriteLine("Serialize finished!");

House house = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<House>(json, settings);
Console.WriteLine($"House number: {house.Number}; Total rooms: {house.Rooms.Count}");

foreach (Room room in house.Rooms)
{
    if (room is Bathroom)
    {
        var temp = room as Bathroom;
        Console.WriteLine($"Room name: {temp.Name}, wet: {temp.IsWet}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Room name: {room.Name}");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Deserialize finished!");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is the JSON string you got after the serialization:

```
{
  "Number": 13,
  "Rooms": [
    {
      "Name": "some room",
      "Floor": 0
    },
    {
      "Name": "other room",
      "Floor": 3
    },
    {
      "$type": "DemoApp.Bathroom, DemoApp",
      "IsWet": true,
      "Name": "Bathroom",
      "Floor": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

And you got back the object after deserialize the string.

Comment: will it work with List<string> instead of string[] ?

Comment: Surely it will :) Take a look at [this post](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm).

Comment: it requires to explicitly specify the type of collection to deserialize to - how would it handle nested Lists and/or classes? Like LIst<House> where House has LIst<Room> as one of its fields

Comment: Thanks! Can it store the type of each class as part of JSON? i.e. how will it handle some class Bathroom derived from class room being added to Rooms List<> (see my edits to initial question)?

Comment: Of course, it's not a problem. See my edited answer.

Comment: AnhTriet, I cannot see types stored in JSON in your edited answer. how will it know that last member of Rooms list should be deserialized as an instance of Bathroom and not Room? did I miss something?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread your question. Please check my edited answer. Notice the `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Comment: looks like what I am looking for, thanks! Now I'll set some experiments with it to find out its limitations (nesting, supported base types, Dictionary<>...). do you know where can I find official list of supported types and other limitations of json.net? could not find it on their official website

Comment: I don't know. I just use Google :) Please don't forget to mark this as answered.

Comment: sure, but I will un-mark it and edit the question if some of them are too severe for what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft.JSON (sometimes known as JSON.NET) is good and available as a NuGet package. Then you can write something like:

```
var value = new { ID = 1, Name="test"};
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
```

And to deserialize (the simplest option, but there are lots of good ways to do it):

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: will it work with non-anonymous types? if yes then will it preserve types after serialization-deserialization cycle?

Comment: Yes it will. Obviously when you deserialize you need to know what type you are expecting. You can use generics as well (e.g. so that you can write the serialization routine once and have lots of different methods call it to serialize different types)

Comment: ADyson, please check EDIT at the beginning of my initial question, part of what I want is to be able to find out what I just deserialized.

Comment: @Tonklin You could use generics. e.g. `public R CallWebService<U, R>(string uri, U value) { R result; ... string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); ...[Call webservice]... result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<R>(response); return result; }`. Doing it this way means the code that calls the webservice doesn't need to know explicitly what data types it's dealing with. Only the code which calls it needs to know. So you can call the same webservice method from many different places using different data types. Does that help?

Comment: what you described is certainly useful in some situations yet what I look for is ability to know the types of data objects from their JSON representation, not ability to ignore them...

Comment: @Tonklin it would be helpful to understand why you want to know that? Are you hoping to trigger a certain action based on the type of data returned?

Comment: I am hoping to deserialize tree-like structure of data objects with a single call, in a way that will return me exactly same structure (including all data types, however nested) as the one that was serialized. All data types are to be shared by sending and receiving sides.

Comment: @Tonklin It's not something I've done directly. The only thing I can think of is this: Assuming your API is written using ASP.NET Web API, in the controller action that returns your data, you can write: `            JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
            {
                SerializerSettings = { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }
            };
            this.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
            this.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters.Add(formatter);`
...cont'd in next comment...

Comment: @Tonklin ...cont'd from above... and in the client side, `                        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray array = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
                        foreach (JObject jo in array)
                        {
                            object ent = jo.ToObject(Type.GetType(jo["$type"].ToString()));` As far as I know, this will enable the server-side to pass the type of the object(s) being returned, and the client can read it. But whether it will pass the type(s) of nested objects I don't know.

Comment: GetType() returns actual type of whatever it is called on (even if it is called on variable of type object and actual type is, say, anonymous) so it should work. but it has to be done manually for each nested List - and manual labor is what I want to avoid. or did I miss something?

Comment: @Tonklin if you don't know the size and scope of the nesting then you might need to do some recursion to go through your tree. But if each item in the tree might have a different type, then it seems logical that you'll have to examine each item individually to check its type. I don't know of any other way to do it in that case.

Comment: ADyson, what I am looking for is serializer that can do it automatically. I know it is possible (if types are stored as part of JSON, as in my example modified some days ago) because I wrote this kind of serializer  already but it was a part of proprietary project so I cannot legally use it in other projects...

Comment: solution offered by AnhTriet seems close to what I want but I am yet to test it

Answer (score 1):

While other answers already provide good solutions, here's one using the [**DataContractJsonSerializer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
var jsonString = "";
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(House));

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
{
    jsonSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, myHouse);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.Write("JSON form of Person object: ");
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

Comment: seems grossly overcomplicated to me, despite the fact that it can be adapted for single-call use by tucking this code into custom static method

Comment: Abbas, will DataContractJsonSerializer handle nested collections like List<>?

Comment: Yes, it will also handle collections.

Comment: will it store types of serialized data objects as part of resulting JSON?

Comment: Abbas, for example: "Rooms": [
    {
      "class": "Room",
      "Name": "some room"
      "Floor": "0",
    },
 - in this piece of JSON there is a field "class" for that, so that if element in serialized List will be of some type derived from Room (not Room itself) it will be deserialized as na instance of that same derived class, not as base class Room